# How to send mails automatically using whenever gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-ec2, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I used when ever gem to send mails every day but it's not sending.I am using `amazon linux ec2` instance. Please look at my code once.

schedule.rb:

```
every 5.minutes do
  runner "Listings.today_expired_spaces"
end
```

Listings.rb:(model-file)

```
  def today_expired_spaces
        @list=List.find_by_date(Date.today)
        UserMailer.today_expired_list(@list).deliver  
  end
```

In production:

After running these commands I am getting responses like this

> 1.whenever -w
>
> [write] crontab file written
>
> 2.whenever -i [write] crontab file updated
>
> 3.whenever
>
> 0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd
>   /home/ubuntu/my_server && bundle exec script/rails runner -e
>   production '\''Spaces.today_expired_spaces'\'''
>
> ### [message] Above is your schedule file converted to cron syntax; your crontab file was not updated.
>
> ### [message] Run `whenever --help' for more options.

Please provide solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should make a `rake task` in `lib/tasks` folder and include the task to whenver schedule file in `config/schedule.rb`

in `lib/tasks/send_mail_bang_bang.rake` (filename just for example only)

```
require 'rake'
namespace :task_namespace do
  desc 'task description'
  task :send_mail => :environment do
    # call Listing method to send mail
    Listings.today_expired_spaces
  end
end
```

in `config/schedule.rb`

```
every 5.minutes do
  rake 'task_namespace:send_mail'
end
```

you can read more about rake task [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html) in "custom-rake-tasks" part

hope it helps

Comment: I think it should work with most servers, that's just plain cron job + rake task using whenever gem, as long as your server running on linux/ubuntu and support RoR ofc